# Nativescript Vue: How to access/manipulate view properties from other components?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a main App.vue with sub components inside.  I am trying to get the scrolling from within my `MovieScreenComponent` to trigger another action in `HeaderComponent`.   Is this possible?  Otherwise, I'd have to have everything in the same component. This is code setup I have right now.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <GridLayout>
        <HeaderComponent />
        <MovieScreenComponent />
    </GridLayout

</template>

<script>
    import HeaderComponent from './components';
    import MovieScreenComponent from './components';


</script>
```

**MovieScreenComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <GridLayout>
        <ScrollView scroll="onScroll"/>
    </GridLayout
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            onScroll: function() {

                 ** How can I change something from within the HeaderComponent, such as image opacity, when I am within another component like this **

            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: do you want to change a prop in your HeaderComponent or what do you want to change?

Comment: @Steven the opacity of an image.  It doesn't seem I'm able to access the view outside of the component if I give it a `ref`and try to access `this.$refs.foo.nativeView.opacity`.

Comment: Could you make a playground example? https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue

Comment: If you are using Vuex, you could store a property that toggles an opacity class in the component, and changing it in `onScroll`

Comment: There are various options, you could use refs Or state and bind attribute to opacity / update store form anywhere Or an event bus. It totally depends on how you want to manage your application.